# AngularUI bootstrap typeahead in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have successfully used UI Bootstrap's typeahead directive on my AngularJS pages, and I would like to create a custom directive for account selection that wraps up the typeahead with some services for fetching the account options.

The options show up just fine, but I think I'm running into issues with the `ng-model` passed as a $scope variable from the outer container to the custom directive - it keeps cutting me off when I try to actually type out the selection in the custom directive.

When using uib-typeahead in my outer controller it works just fine and waits forever for you to finish typing/make your selection.  But when doing it in the directive, the `ng-model-options: { debounce: 50 }` seems to cause the user's typing to reset to empty after the debounce interval.  At 50 ms I basically can get only a character or two in there, and then the $viewValue (?) is reset, and it often garbles both the possible selection and the placeholder in the text box. If I set the debounce to a higher value, then it gives me longer before it resets, but it is also that much slower to react to user input.

I'm guessing the issue has something to do with the `ng-model`, its underlying `ngModelController` and the `$viewValue` in there, but I'm not sure how to get it to let me finish typing.

Plunker demo can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BRMIyU9KyKfcWRyX3hS6?p=preview)

[image: The Typeahead row works fine - the custom directive that *includes* the typeahead has the issue]

#### WORKS: uib-typeahead

```
<input type="text"
       name="account2"
       uib-typeahead="account as formatAccount(account) for account in accounts | filter:$viewValue"
       placeholder="Select an account"
       ng-model="selectedAccount"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 50 }"
       typeahead-show-hint="true"
       typeahead-focus-first="true"
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-min-length="0"
       class="form-control account-search"
       autocomplete="off" />
```

---

#### DOESN'T WORK: Reference to the directive

```
<input type="text"
       name="account3"
       input-account
       accounts="accounts"
       placeholder="Select your account"
       ng-model="selectedAccount" />
```

#### The impatient directive

```
app.directive('inputAccount', [

  function() {

    let directive = 
      {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: 'true',
        require: ['ngModel'],
        templateUrl: 'input-account.html',
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=ngModel',
          accounts: '=',
          placeholder: '@',
          name: '@',
          required: '@'
        },
        link: linkFunction
      };

    return directive;

    function linkFunction($scope) {

      $scope.formatAccount = function (account) {

          if (account) {
              return `${account.id} - ${account.name}`;
          }

          return '';

      };  // formatAccount


    }


  }

]);   // inputAccount directive
```

#### The impatient directive's template

```
<input type="text"
       name="{{ name }}"
       placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
       ng-model="ngModel"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 50 }"
       uib-typeahead="account as formatAccount(account) for account in accounts | filter:$viewValue"
       typeahead-show-hint="true"
       typeahead-focus-first="true"
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-min-length="0"
       class="form-control account-search"
       autocomplete="off"
       ng-required="required" />
```